# Two similar applications on different domains but same users

Tags: mysql, database-design, zend-framework

I'm planning on building two applications using Zend Framework that are very similar but serve two different purposes that can't be part of the same application or be combined into one. However, modules are something I'm considering.

The issue I'm running into is if a user registers for the first application I want that information be available to the second application, hence sharing a user table or user database. Because the applications are so similar that they have the same database tables with some having different fields, I'm not sure if I should have three, two or one databases. Three databases would be User Database, App1 Database, App2 Database. Two databases would be User Database and App1+2 Database with prefixed tables. One database would be User and App1+2 Database.

I'm trying to give as much information as possible, but because this is for a client I can't really discuss the details in depth. Also, this is something the client wants and other than not being able to figure out how to set it up, I'm not sure this is best.

**My Questions**

1. Of the options above, which would
   serve best, or other?
2. Should I have a shared user dataset across two applications or should the users have to register again?
3. No matter of the choice you think is best, how would/should I implement it into Zend? Just a brief is needed no need for code.

I hope this is enough information to give me the best answer, but if more information is need, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have multiple databases? Use just one database and prefix the tables that differ for the two applications. For example:

`users`
`app1_otherdata`
`app2_otherdata`

This way users' data will be easily accessible to both apps and you could still have a relatively independent database structures.

Comment: Multiple database was a suggestion because then I can have the applications on different servers and not be dependent on one database. Although it would be make life easier in terms of setting up the logic I'm not sure in the long run it would be worth it.

Comment: Well, since it seems that having the same userdata on both applications is a requirement you will depend on one database either way.

Answer (score 0):

Question 2 is something you really should discuss with your client.

Once you know your clients' preference you could eg. suggest using a single sign-on approach for the sites, but I would certainly keep both DBs apart. So either your 2 DB (with separate user DB per app) or your 3 DB solution (with separate user DB/single sign-on) makes more sense to me.

Comment: The problem is the client doesn't know best practice and neither do I in terms of which set up is best. I agree that not having the two applications sharing the same users would be the best way to go about this.